# Placing a Text over another Text in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays, text-manipulation

How can I place a text on top of another text in beamer? I want something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8923/172097) but over text while the original text becomes transparent.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! - Do you mean https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52667/124842 ?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164948/scary-font-echo-effect

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The title of your link is too scary to follow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick hack: use a negative space to move overlays in different states of uncovering on top of each other

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{%
    still covered={\opaqueness<1>{20}},
    again covered={\opaqueness<1->{20}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \Huge

    \uncover<1>{old text}

    \visible<2>{\vspace*{-\baselineskip} new text}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! But the new text is not placed on the first line if I have multiple lines. How to fix this?

Comment: @Lod If you have multiple lines, you could some use multiple of `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` e.g. `\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}`. Or use tikz (in particular the tikzmarks library) if you need more flexibility.